# PHP For Loop str_replace emoticons

Tags: php, for-loop, str-replace

I'm pretty new to PHP so please bear with me for this one.

I have an array with emoticons, and I want to replace the emoticon text with the correct image, all within a for loop. So I'm trying to take my text variable and do a str_replace, but I'm not sure exactly how to display the text after the emoticons have been changed.

Here is my code:

```
$content = ":D Here is a sample sentence for this example :)";

$emotes = array(
    [":)","<img class='emoticon' src='smile.png'>"], 
    [":D","<img class='emoticon' src='grin.png'>"],
);
for($i=0;$i<count($emotes);$i++) {
   $contentWithEmotes = str_replace($emotes[$i][0], $emotes[$i][1], $content);
}
print $contentWithEmotes;
```

The problem this this is that it only displays the last image from the array, when I want it to display both of them.
How should I go about displaying the content with the correct image?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The problem is that each time through the loop, you're proessing the original `$content`, not the result of the previous replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restructure your array like this:

```
$emotes = [
    ":)"=>"<img class='emoticon' src='smile.png' />",
    ":D"=>"<img class='emoticon' src=grin.png' />"
];
```

Then use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$contentWithEmotes = strtr($content,$emotes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop you need to process the result of the previous time, not the original content.

```
$contentWithEmotes = $content;
foreach ($emotes as $emote) {
   $contentWithEmotes = str_replace($emote[0], $emote[1], $contentWithEmotes);
}
```

However, the `strtr()` solution is better.